# Receiving data in node.js

Tags: sockets, node.js

I am having a java program send data to me over a specific socket to my node.js application. I want to be able to obtain all of the data, which is information from a SQlite database, and send it off to something else.

I've found something like the following can work but it seems to be unreliable as data is missing and sometimes it doesn't even show up.

```
stream.addListener('data', function(data){
buffer.write(data.toString());
});
```

on a side note, I need the socket to stay open so I can't call the "end" event.

I really don't have any attachment to stream.addListener so i can use something else if it works how i want. Basically what i'm asking is, What is the most effective way to obtain data from a socket using node.js?

P.S. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` event is not guaranteed to have all the data sent to it in one go. You'll need to build up a buffer over multiple events and watch for delimiters of some kind (newlines, null characters, whatever you feel). Here's an example from a project where I'm parsing data from IRC (converted from CoffeeScript); `parseData` is the event handler for the `data` event (e.g. `socket.on('data', this.parseData);`):

```js
IrcConnection.prototype.parseData = function(data) {
  var line, lines, i;

  data = data.replace("\r\n", "\n");
  this.buffer += data;
  lines = this.buffer.split("\n");
  this.buffer = "";

  /* Put the last line back in the buffer if it was incomplete */
  if (lines[lines.length - 1] !== '') {
    this.buffer = lines[lines.length - 1];
  }

  /* Remove the final \n or incomplete line from the array */
  lines = lines.splice(0, lines.length - 1);
  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    line = lines[i];
    this.emit('raw', line);
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried something like this and it works to an extent, by the way i like your code better than mine, but i have some lost data. I think the issue is that node.js says "data will be lost if there is no listener when a Readable Stream emits a 'data' event.". I'll try out your code implementation though and see if it fixes it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: One solution to that issue is to make sure you attach the `data` event listener before you connect the socket.

Comment: really dumb question, but what is IrcConnection in your program?

Comment: It's a constructor function (actually, it's a CoffeeScript class) that manages an IRC connection. I only listed the function that responds to the `data` event, but it has other functions for handling other events and managing the state of the socket.